# Why is it customary for Jews to grow beards?

Tags: minhag, beard

What is the reason for growing one's beard? Many rabbis have beards. Why?

Comment: http://www.myjewishlearning.com/practices/Ethics/Our_Bodies/Adorning_the_Body/Beards_and_Sidelocks.shtml  http://www.jccmb.com/templates/articlecco_cdo/aid/1339529/jewish/Beards.htm

Comment: The Chafetz Chaim wrote a kuntres called Tiferes Adam which discusses the importance of the beard and peyos.

Comment: It was historically hard to remove them in a halachikly permissible fashion.

Comment: @Dan the first line of that "My Jewish Learning" article says, "All agree that there is no ban on shaving with an electric razor."  Where'd they come up with _that_"??

Comment: maybe the author means "all [within the Masorti movement] agree"

Comment: @DoubleAA did they not have scissors historically?

Comment: @NaftaliTzvi They did. It's hard to remove a beard with scissors. You can just trim it.

Comment: Does anyone know the reason some groups have a minhag davka to shave before marriage, then? (I don't mean with a blade and I don't mean the prohibited corners. Which groups have this minhag, by the way? I was definitely told that some do.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The debatable:

- Kabbalistic sources about beards, or about spiritually-destructive forces involved in removing a beard. Much ink has been spilled over how much facial hair was worn by the kabbalist Rabbi Menachem Azariah of Fano.
- Cutting your beard means you're trying to look like a non-Jew. Chasam Sofer vehemently opposes this argument, observing that in Biblical times, pagan men had beards too.
- The Tzemach Tzedek (the 3rd Lubavitcher Rebbe) was of the opinion that you're trying to look feminine by removing your beard, which violates the prohibition on cross-dressing.

The practical:

- Men are prohibited from shaving their jaw line ("five corners of the face", more or less) with a razor. So until a few decades ago, your only options were a scissors (which could trim your beard but not really eliminate it altogether) or depilatory powder (a strong base that would dissolve the hair). Today, most Americans follow the opinion of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (and others) that most electric shavers are considered "scissors", not razors as they can't cut at 0 rpm; but some (such as Chazon Ish) disagree.
- There are various times in the year when shaving, haircuts, and other grooming are frowned-upon for men. (E.g. the three weeks commemorating the destruction of the Temple in Jerusalem.) Thus growing a beard all the time was just easier.
- Why waste the time shaving?

Comment: I don't understand the last point. Why waste time cutting your hair or trimming your toe-nails?

Comment: +1. @ShimonbM, to not have a beard, most men need to shave daily or so. To not have unruly hair or toenails, most men need to cut them far less often.

Comment: I'm thinking "the Tzemach Tzedek ruled" might be a better phrasing. Right now it seems like a Rebbishe/Chassidishe "feeling" when it was instead a psak halacha (which is, as you noted, debated). (My two cents, thoughts?)

Comment: @HodofHod Wait, I thought the Tzemach Tzedek's issue was with scissors as a form of gilach, not that it was beged isha. The former could still apply today, but the latter is very hard to argue for in today's world.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Having never made it all the way through the TT's tshuva myself, I have only other people's words to go on: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/494236/jewish/Why-dont-chassidic-men-shave.htm Also, shaving was not that [uncommon in his days either](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicholas_I_of_Russia)

Comment: @HodofHod The only teshuva of the TT on the matter I know of (there may be others) is this one http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30499&st=&pgnum=447 which doesn't mention beged isha at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA This is the main tshuva that people refer to: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1614&pgnum=164 It's pages 164-178 (which is why I haven't read the whole thing yet). In the very first column he mentions "lo yilbash" as well as throughout.

Answer (score 10):

R Shlomo Aviner, in *Shut She'elat Shlomo*, mentions 4 reasons, which are brought here in short:

1. The *gmara* in Shabbat 152a, says that the splendor of man's face is the beard `הדרת פנים זקן`. That's the natural and *whole* looks of the Israeli man, as R Yehonatan Aibeshitz mentions in *Ya'art  Dvash, part A*.
2. The daily shaving is bothersome and causes *bitul torah* (not learning torah at that time).
3. Whoever shaves daily, on *Shabbat* he cannot. So on Shabbat he's *Menuval* - not tidy. Same happens on holidays and Shabbats of *Ben HaMetzarim* and during *Sfirat HaOmer*.
4. Even today, with the electric shavers, it isn't trivial that it's allowed to shave using them. Many Rabbis have ruled against it. Even those that approved it, stated that the machine oughtn't be pressed strongly to the skin and the skin oughtn't be stretched. New machines with new techniques for making the shave closer to the skin make their Halachich approval even harder.

Comment: "[Israeli](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelis)"? Do you mean ["Israelite"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelites)?

Comment: @msh210 If so it's called in English then be it. In Hebrew, OTOH, I humbly disagree with Wikipedia that translates Isralite as `בן ישראל`. It's explicit that an Israelite is also called `ישראלי`, as in `בן האשה הישראלית`. And there are well many examples in Orthodox Jewish literature for that, and it's also used in everyday Hebrew in Israel (I should know...).

Answer (score 0):

the Meam Loez on Bereishis says the lion was given a beard to give it a majestic appearance (since it is king of the animals).

Hence, a beard is supposed to give a majestic appearance. So too regarding man. Judaism views man as a the crowning glory and ultimate purpose of creation.

Perhaps not shaving the beard is to remind a person of his great importance and mission in this world.

Answer (score 0):

The book "Haderet Panim" a 400 plus page book about the beard which deals mainly with the halachic sources, citing Gemarrah, Minhag, Ktuvim and some sources in Zohar quote  the   Ari Z"L as saying that :
"The hairs of the head are tzinaros of tumah while the hair of the beard are tzinaros of Kedusha.Tzinaros being "vessles". Modern biology 400 years later showed also that human hair is hollow like a drinking straw.

Comment: How does this answer the question? We would want the beard hairs to be shorter so the kedusha doesn't have as far to travel to get through the pipe.

Comment: "Gemarrah, Minhag, Ktuvim and [] Zohar": erm...that's quite the variety, I guess.

Comment: I am simply mentioning what the Holy Ari said. On him is  your comment.As for the book "haderet HaPanim" a very large group of Torah Jews got together around 1982 and published the 400 plus page book of sources (which I mentioned) and subsidized the publication so that the book then cost me 4 (four) shekels to buy. My point was only to make Parve the book lest someone jest (Chas v Chalilah) on my only mentioning the Holy Ari....and they that can understand will understand.

Comment: I'm just not sure you are applying the quote correctly in context.

Comment: some sources in Zohar quote the Ari Z"L?